# Reduce an array to just the 'named' keys

Tags: php, arrays

I would like a hint or much better a solution for this:

I do a regular expresion match to an url for example '/product/100/'

```
preg_match('/^\/(?<name>\w+)\/(?<digit>\d+)\/$/', '/product/100/', $matches);
```

As result of this I get the following array on `$matches`:

```
array
  0 => string '/product/100/' (length=13)
  'name' => string 'product' (length=7)
  1 => string 'product' (length=7)
  'digit' => string '100' (length=3)
  2 => string '100' (length=3)
```

How can I use reduce this array to get this?

```
array
  'name' => string 'product' (length=7)
  'digit' => string '100' (length=3)
```

After I get the matching expresions, I call a function and give the 'named' keys as arguments to the function.

```
call_user_func_array($view, $just_named_args_no_integer_keys);
```

I hope anyone can give me any hint.

Best Regards

Comment: Come to that, what is `$just_named_args_no_integer_keys`?

Comment: $view would be the name of the function to call, like 'homepage', 'product_detail', like that. $just_named_args_no_integer_keys would be the second array in the post. Thank you for the response :)

Comment: $just_named_args_no_integer_keys is his array with only the name/digit

Comment: Why would you need this?  Can't you ignore unused parts?

Comment: I was doing that, eventualy it get to confuse, as I have a view "function product_detail($foo_arg, $name, $foo_arg2, $digit, $foo_arg3):" for me there is to many confuse args, as it is for me best "function product_detail($name, $digit):" Remember that i call the call_user_func_array('product_detail', $array_with_the_args)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just run the keys you get from array_keys() through array_filter():

```
/* This is for PHP 5.3, I'm sure you'll figure out how to the same thing pre 5.3 :) */

$allKeys = array_keys($view);
$namedKeys = array_filter($allKeys, function($value) { return !is_numeric($value); });
```

**Update**

Did not read the question properly. In this case, actually just foreach over the data:

```
$namedValues = array();
foreach ($view as $key => $value)
    if (!is_numeric($key))
        $namedValues[$key] = $value;
```

Comment: Pre-5.3, the second argument is: `create_function('$value', 'return !is_numeric($value);')`

Comment: @strager sure, although I would strongly suggest, for maintenance reasons to just create an actual function.